# What does the TypeScript type parameter refer to?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I'm trying to figure out exactly what the "type parameter " is typing in functions with this syntax.

```
getStuff<T>(id: string): Observable<T> {
  return id;
}
```

Does the `<T>` in `getStuff<T>` refer to the parameter type being passed into the function, or the return value type?

I have already reviewed the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) about generics but I still couldn't get a definitive answer.

Comment: We’ve now added a type variable T to the identity function. This T allows us to capture the type the user provides (e.g. number), so that we can use that information later. Here, we use T again as the return type. On inspection, we can now see the same type is used for the argument and the return type. This allows us to traffic that type information in one side of the function and out the other.

Comment: Type T is specifying the return type i.e. Observable<T>. Note that this code sample is wrong though as it's returning a string not an Observable of type T.

Comment: Please don't edit the question so drastically when there are already answers, which you are invalidating. If you realize your question is wrong, ask a new one, and link to this one. You should know, however, that your edited snippet would still not compile. T doesn't exist as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `<T>` in the function declaration will refer to any other `T` in the function.

In this case, the only other T is in the return type of the function `Observable<T>`, meaning that it the function will return a value of type `Observable<T>`.

---

```
getStuff<T>(id: string): Observable<T>
```

`getStuff` is the name of the function.

`<T>` indicates that it is a generic function that will use a generic type T throughout the function when referenced.

`id` is the name of the parameter.

`: string` indicates that the parameter's type is a `string`.

`: Observable<T>` indicates that the return type of the function.

Comment: So in plain English, would you say "This function will accept T as a parameter and also return T"?  Or can it be one or the other, for example "This function will accept T as a parameter" then you can type the return value a different way?

Comment: is there a way to make sure T is a certain type, for example: it MUST have a certain base class or implement a certain interface?
EDIT: In C#, you have the where keyword.